# Convergent series proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

Suppose that $\{x_m\}$ is a sequence of positive, non-zero numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {x_n}$ diverges, and let $S_n = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$. If for all $n \geq 2$, $\frac{x_n}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{S_nS_{n-1}}$, show that $\sum \frac{x_n}{S_n^2}$ converges.

My attempt:

Notice that $\frac{x_n}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{S_n - S_{n-1}}{S_nS_{n-1}} \leq S_n - S_{n-1} = x_n$.

The Cauchy criterion is satisfied meaning that $\sum \frac{x_n}{S_n^2}$ converges.

I strongly believe that my attempt is wrong but I'm not sure how to go about the proof. Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Any typo in your condition? $S_n-S_{n-1}=x_n$, so your condition amounts to $\frac 1 {S_n}\leq \frac 1 {S_{n-1}}$ which  is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

$$\frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_nS_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{S_n}$$

The RHS gives a telescoping series.

Comment: Yes, thank you!